# Did Voltaire drink 40-50 cups of coffee a day?

Tags: history, coffee

From [9 Famous Geniuses Who Were Also Huge Coffee Addicts](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/famous-coffee-drinkers_n_5358495):

> Voltaire is said to have drunk 40-50 cups of coffee a day.

Elsewhere, from [Did Voltaire really drink 40 to 50 cups of coffee a day?](https://drinkswithoutborders.com/voltaire-coffee/)  Stephen G. Tallentyre (which is the pen name of Evelyn Beatrice Hall) wrote that:

> He dined in Paris that night at a coffee-house, with a few other literary men. He arrived rather late. He had come straight from Versailles, and alone of the company knew what had occurred there. He made his dinner, after his frugal fashion, off seven or eight cups of black coffee and a couple of rolls, and was very talkative and amusing.”
>
> Stephen G. Tallentyre, The Life of Voltaire (1903)

But this says only about dinner, and not the whole day.

---

From [Cincinnati Lancet and Clinic](https://www.geriwalton.com/voltaires-coffee-obsession/), p. 15.

> “[T]he philosopher took as high as fifty cups on some days. This would perhaps explain the nobility of Voltaire’s mind and its sudden bursts of enthusiasm, for, according to Condorcet (*Vie de Voltaire*) he passed in an instant from wrath to tenderness, from violent indignation to sunny pleasantness.”

Here it says 50 cups.

Comment: That's better, thanks. For ref. the Marquis de Condorcet's work  referenced can be found [on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_eWNvVj2_o58C/page/n15/mode/2up), but my French isn't that great to find the specific page. It's difficult to imagine what could provide better support for the argument that he did do so than his friends' telling us, but maybe he confessed it somewhere himself.

Comment: 40 cups = 2.5 gallons; 50 cups = 3.125 gallons.  At least, assuming the modern definition of a "_cup_".

Comment: @Nat They could be demitasses, so not necessarily 8 fluid ounces.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Good point!  If we take Wikipedia's estimate of 60-to-90 mL per [demitasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demitasse), average that to 75 mL of coffee per "_cup_", then "_40 cups_" would be about 3000 mL (3L or ~0.792 gallons).  Then assuming (95 mg-caffeine)/(237 mL-coffee) (per Google's display-info), that'd be about ~1203 mg-caffeine.

Comment: It sounds like loads, but it's well below the [LD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine#Severe_intoxication) of 150-200 mg/kg (estimated) for humans.

Comment: Apparently ["_caffeinism_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeinism) had been associated with 1000-to-1500 mg-caffeine/day.

Comment: @Nat Being Voltaire french, they were surely italian-type expressos, and 50 cups would barely make a liter.

Comment: Is there evidence that coffee was served in the same size of cup in the 18th century as today? Or what serving size was used?